# How will $0<\theta <1$ influence this solution

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood

Given are $n$ samples $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ from the following distribution:

$$f(x;\theta)=\theta(1-\theta)^{x-1}$$

where $0<\theta<\frac{1}{2}$ and $x\in\{1,2,3\ldots\}$

Find the [MLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) estimator $\hat {\theta}_{MLE}$

I have found that $\hat {\theta}_{MLE}=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n(x_k-1)\right)}$ by the work shown in the end of this post.

How do I use the fact that $0<\theta<\frac{1}{2}$?

Please correct me if I made an error on the MLE calculation.

Finding the MLE:
$$\hat {\theta}_{MLE}=\arg{\max_{N}{(l(\theta))}}=\arg{\max_{N}{(\log(L(\theta)))}}=\arg{\max_{N}{(\log(\prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i|\theta)))}}$$
$$\hat {\theta}_{MLE}=\arg{\max_{N}{\left(\log(\prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i|\theta))\right)}}=\arg{\max_{N}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\log(f(x_i|\theta))\right)}}$$$$\hat {\theta}_{MLE}=\arg{\max_{N}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\log(\theta(1-\theta)^{x_i-1})\right)}}=\arg{\max_{N}{\left(n\log(\theta)+\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-\theta)^{x_i-1}\right)}}$$$$\hat {\theta}_{MLE}=\arg{\max_{N}{\left(n\log(\theta)+\log(1-\theta)\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-1)\right)}}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d \theta} \left( n\log(\theta)+\log(1-\theta)\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-1) \right)=\frac{n}{\theta}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-1)}{1-\theta}=0$$$$(1-\theta)n=\theta \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-1)$$
$$n=\theta \left(n+\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-1)\right)$$
$$1=\theta \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-1)\right)$$
$$\hat{\theta}_{MLE}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-1)}$$

Comment: You have already used it.. you have divided by $\theta$ at one point and by $1-\theta$ in another moment. Of course this divisions wouldn't be right if $\theta=0$ or 1.  Also search 'geometric random variable' so you will understand what the likelihood is all about here. Also all steps seem right just from a quick check.

Comment: Instead of saying that $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are $n$ samples, one should say that $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is a sample of size $n$. $\qquad$

Comment: @JoaquinSan In another part of the question $0<\theta<\frac{1}{2}$. Will that have any affect on the answer?(see edit)

Comment: Yes, you are estimating the value of theta, so what happens if beforehand you know theta is smaller than a half but when you use this estimator it turns out it is bigger than 1/2?? Would that be a good estimator? Of course not so your best estimator would be .. in case ... and ... in case... I leave the dots so you can finish this.

Comment: If you think this was enough I can write it as an answer later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this answer is adding to what I commented.

For  general version of the maximum likelihood estimator you need a little more than what it is written. If the parameter $\theta$ is known to take values in a set $ \Theta$ then

$$ \hat{\theta}_{MLE} = \arg \max_{ \theta \in \Theta} (\hat{l}(\theta)) $$

Note the difference of notation between $ l(\theta) $ and $ \hat{l} (\theta) $. The first one denotes the ''real likelihood'' while the second one considers using the sample.

Now let's make sense of this idea: Suppose for example that you have want to estimate a parameter $ \theta$ which for some reason (probably nature of the experiment, some physical law, anything) is known to be in $ (0,1)$  . Then, imagine that you use the technique of derivation, and you get a formula for the estimator. But when you plug the value of the data into this formula it happens that your estimator is $1000$. Would that estimator make sense?

Of course not, so you have to restrict to maximize likelihood to the values for which it actually make sense.

In your example, you need to verify that the value of your formula satisfies the restriction. But what if it does not? How would you know how  to compute the MLE?. It turns out that in many useful cases direct differentiation is not the most helpful example, in those cases you probably need to analyze the maximum with other techniques you should know from calculus.

Note that 'the mistake' (it's not totally wrong) in your work is not considering the indicator functions. 
$$ \arg \max_{ \theta \in \Theta} \hat{l}(\theta) = \arg \max \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i | \theta) \cdot 1_{\Theta}(\theta,x_i) $$
IN your particular example, as $x_i$ come from identical distributions we can simplify: 
$$ \arg \max_{ \theta \in \Theta} \hat{l}(\theta) =\arg \max \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i | \theta) \cdot 1_{(0,1)}(\theta) =  1_{(0,1)}(\theta)\arg \max \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i | \theta) $$

So I hope this explains what you needed.

Comment: To really get a mature concept try calculating MLE of a sample where the distribution of $ x_i$ depends on $i$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This is very helpful. I eventually went with: $$\hat{\theta}_{MLE}= \begin{cases}
    0.5       & \quad \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-1)\leq n\\
    \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-1)}  & \quad \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-1)>n\\
  \end{cases}$$ Is it correct?

Comment: seems reasonable